# Поиск и получение значения символа из разделяемой библиотеки в linux

Tags: c++, linux

Есть проект, в котором собираются .so библиотеки и сам исполняемый файл.
В одной из библиотек(назовём её libsettings.so) находится символ softVersion, который представляет собой простую СИ строку и которая используется для определения версии всего приложения.
Мне хотелось бы при сборке создать простой архив, который имеет вид x-soft.tar.gz,
где x это версия приложения, которая задается в библиотеке libsettings.so.
С помощью утилиты strings я могу достать версию использую простой grep, но если ли способ получить значение символа по его имени?
Использую GCC 9.0.0 Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: А не проще ли во время сборки библиотеки дописать ей версию в имя?

Comment: Подгружаете библиотеку ([dlopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)) и берете адрес символа через [dlsym](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)

Comment: Интересное решение делать это через dlsym)

Comment: `v=$(ваша.программа --version); touch ${v}-soft.tar.gz`

Comment: Отличный вариант, но к сожалению в моем случае не рабочий, так как сборка происходит кросскомпилятором